# Chat box scroll to bottom scroll to the end of the page not end of the chat

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have chatbox and this is my html code

```
                         <div class="card-body msg_card_body card-footer" >
                            <template v-for='(data,data_id) in active_chat_datas ' class='card-footer' id='scrollable' >
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-start mb-4 last-footer" v-if="data['to_facebook_id'] == null">
                                    <div class="img_cont_msg">
                                        <img :src="active_customer['facebook_messages_link']" class="rounded-circle user_img_msg" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="msg_cotainer">
                                        @{{data['message']}}
                                        <span class="msg_time" style='width:250px;'>@{{date_format(data['created_at'])}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div v-else class="d-flex justify-content-end mb-4 last-footer">
                                    <div class="msg_cotainer_send">
                                        @{{data['message']}}
                                        <span class="msg_time_send" style='width:100px;'>@{{date_format(data['created_at'])}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="img_cont_msg">
                                        <img src="https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/001292/481/WV/_D.jpg" class="rounded-circle user_img_msg" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </template>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mb-4" id='myid'>
                                <div class="msg_cotainer_send ">
                                    <span class="msg_time_send" style='width:100px;'></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

and i have this js code

```
$('#myid').stop ().animate ({
    scrollTop: $('#myid')[0].scrollHeight
});
```

when the code

```
scrollTop: $('#myid')[0].scrollHeight
```

execute the scrol go to the end of the page not of the chat
like this pictures
[image]

but i need it to scroll to the botton of the chat like this picture
[image]

and this is sandbox link
https://bo1lej.csb.app/

https://codesandbox.io/s/bo1lej

how can i do that thanks ..

Comment: You will need to provide more code, also you should add the `vue` tag, you are using vue and jQuery together? only vue should have all the funcionality you need

Comment: Can you convert your code into a snippet that reproduces the problem?

Comment: this is sandbox link https://bo1lej.csb.app/ https://codesandbox.io/s/bo1lej

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $(".msg_card_body").scrollTop($(".msg_card_body")[0].scrollHeight);
 });
</script>
```

***this anwser is based on the sandbox you provided***

Comment: i gat this error message Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollHeight')

Comment: this is sandbox link https://bo1lej.csb.app/

Comment: I have edited my answer, can please check, i have tested this on your sandbox also it is working

Answer (score 1):

Try this code below,

```
$("#custommyid").animate(
  { scrollTop: $("#custommyid")[0].scrollHeight },
  2000
);
```

This is the working code.[click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/chatappscroll-oj5tq1?file=/index.html)
In the provided sandbox,I make scrolling the chat app when the page loads ,since you didnt provide the chat url for getting chat messages and load it on the frontend.

I will give some knowledge about this. Because later someone can revist this and can learn this instead of just looking the code.animate function use to smoth the scrolling functionality. we can set this trasition.In here I set 2000ms seconds.
And there some important point there.You can see that I have used "scrollHeight".It means total container height.there are couple of other concepts there.just see below

scrollTop -by now how amount of height user has scroll

clientHeight -how much of amount that user see in the container

Comment: i gat this error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollHeight')"

Comment: @softya can you share the code with sandbox url

Comment: this is sandbox link https://bo1lej.csb.app/

Comment: @softya I modify the code by adding my answer with codesand box url. please check.In there. I have done some changes.I used Id as "custommyid" and add  this id to chat content warpper div.

Comment: @softya  if this work as you expected, please accept this as answer. Thank you!

Comment: welcome friend! @softya